# PHP session with memcached. session_destroy() does not delete memcache entry

Tags: php, session, memcached

I'm getting a really odd behaviour while using memcached for handling session.
Looks like my users are sharing session, for (at the moment) no reason.

Use case:

I'm logged in, getting PHPSESSID of 'xxx'. For no reason another user from another computer get's the same PHPSESSID and of course see's my profile and all other session data.

From top of your heads, what could be the reason for session_start() to give out SESSID which was already created?

After hours of debug, the only 'strange' thing I noticed that 'Logout' action does not delete memcached entry of that session.

```
// Resume session.
session_start();

// Unset all session data.
$_SESSION[V::$SESS_NAME] = array();

// Kill session cookie.
if(ini_get('session.use_cookies'))
{
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    // Send this cookie to the past. Time travel - possible!
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);
}

// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Does anyone else experienced similar behaviour while working with PHP memcached session?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

After some debug, I did identify the problem, which was caused by Varnish. Apparently pages are being cached with headers.

Edge-case:

- User A comes to website, request fresh (no cookies), gets a varnish MISS and get's a session cookie. Log's in.
- User B comes to website, request fresh (no cookies), gets a varnish HIT. Varnish sends out headers (with Set-Cookie) of previously cashed page. User B gets a session cookie with session_id of User A. User B gets automatically logged in into User A profile.

Sorry for not pointing out, that stack had Varnish running. Was not aware myself before went into deep ends of debug.

Comment: @userfuser set-cookie header does not go into cache and when HIT does not go back to response.

Comment: in my case Varnish was also to blame. But for me, Varnish was apparently also caching the cookied pages, because in the browser the PHP session was for a moment there, then gone, then back a bit later. After disabling Varnish, issues went away.

Answer (score 0):

memcached and PHP's session functions (like `session_destroy()`) are not related. `session_destroy()` only ends a PHP session; it has nothing to do with memcached. If you want to delete memcached entries as well, you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Hm... So, session_start() does add memc.sess.key.SESSIONID to memcached, writing to $_SESSION does write values to memc.sess.key.SESSIONID, however session_destroy() does NOT delete memc.sess.key.SESSIONID from memcached? If this is true, do you know this from experience or is there a link I could get a read?